# How to attach to nodemon process with WebStorm and TypeScript setting

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I use debugger "attach to node.js/chrome".

### My WebStorm debugger configuration.

- Host: localhost
- port: 9229
- attach to: Chrome or node.js > 6.3 started with `--inspect`

[image]

I am using TypeScript. My tsconfig.json file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es6",
    /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",
    /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    "sourceMap": true,
    /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    "outDir": "dist",
    /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",               /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,
    /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    "baseUrl": "./dist",
    /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    "sourceRoot": "src",
    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    "mapRoot": "./dist",
    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
    /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/**/*.spec"
  ]
}
```

My nodemon process is run by `npm run debug`.

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "debug": "NODE_ENV=dev nodemon --inspect dist/bin/www.js"
  }
}
```

I want to attach debugger to nodemon process.

What configuration is necessary?

If you need other information to find problem, please ask me more information.

Comment: your configuration should just work... Please see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.3/running-and-debugging-node-js.html#nodemon. I can only suggest changing `--inspect` to `--inspect-brk` to get execution suspended until the debugger is attached to make sure that 'early' breakpoints are hit

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Restarting PC solved problem. It seems bug of webstorm or something.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy you need to specify port in the `inspect`.

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "debug": "NODE_ENV=dev nodemon --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 dist/bin/www.js"
  }
```

}