# How to run Nodemon with TypeScript in debug mode in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, webstorm, nodemon, ts-node

I have a very basic Express server setup with NodeJS/Express + Nodemon.  I'm using WebStorm as my IDE.

When running the debug/inspect script, my application is throwing a compile-time error. Following the instructions [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/running-and-debugging-node-js.html#nodemon), and cognizant of the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60359419/how-to-attach-to-nodemon-process-with-webstorm-and-typescript-setting), my (simplified) `package.json` looks like this:

```json
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon src/app.ts",
    "debug": "nodemon --inspect=127.0.0.1:9229 src/app.ts"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.9",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.19",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  }
```

When I run `npm run debug` I receive the following error:

[image]

I've also tried the following, all with the same result:

- `"debug": "nodemon --inspect src/app.ts"`
- `"debug": "nodemon --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 src/app.ts"`

Any ideas why this error is occurring?

The command `npm run dev` does not generate an error.  Upon further investigation, nodemon automatically substitutes ts-node when targeting a `.ts` file.  Ts-node, in turn, [recommends](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) debugging by registering ts-node and running the server with the node command.

> If you need to use advanced node.js CLI arguments (e.g. --inspect),
> use them with `node -r ts-node/register` instead of the ts-node CLI.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can modify your script as follows:

```
"debug": "nodemon --exec \"node --inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229 --require ts-node/register src/app.ts\""
```

to make sure that the `--inspect-brk` is passed to Node.js and not to `ts-node`

Comment: Thanks!  I hope you guys can put this into your core documentation!

Comment: I don't fully understand the `--exec`, could you also put this in a _nodemon.json_ file? It would be nice if you could put some more text into it to provide more info about what is going on here.

Comment: just coming here to say thanks

Comment: For me this works only with: `--inspect=` instead of: `--inspect-brk=`

Comment: I had to manually install ts-node, but then this worked. `npm i -D ts-node`